# Add column with values as UUID with not-null and unique constraints in one changeset

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, constraints, uuid, liquibase

In `mysql` database I have `user` table and I need to add `user_key` column where values will be computed as `uuid()`. Values in this column should be unique and not null.

So I wrote this changeset:

```
   <changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
        <preConditions>
            <not>
                <columnExists tableName="user" columnName="user_key"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <addColumn tableName="user">
            <column name="user_key" type="varchar(36)" defaultValueComputed="uuid()" (or valueComputed="uuid()")>
                <constraints unique="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

but it fails with the following error (which seems reasonable, since MySQL doesn't allow functions as default values):

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'uuid() NOT NULL' at line 1
>
> [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE
>   user ADD user_key VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT uuid() NOT
>   NULL]

But isn't `defaultValueComputed` (or `valueComputed`) was supposed to deal with it?

Surely, I can create such column by writing multiple changesets (create column, update it's values with `uuid()`, add constraints), but is it possible to implement this with only `<addColumn>` tag?

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7